# Google analytics with ionic3 notworking for ios

Tags: ionic-framework, google-analytics, ionic3, ionic-native

I'm implementing Google analytics for my ionic 3 app, i have followed the following [link](https://www.freakyjolly.com/add-google-analytics-in-ionic-3-application-using-cordova-and-ionic-native-plugin/) `https://www.freakyjolly.com/add-google-analytics-in-ionic-3-application-using-cordova-and-ionic-native-plugin/`

Everything is smooth for android but for ios,google tracker is responding but resulting null.

```
this.ga.startTrackerWithId('UA-XXXXXXXXX-X')
      .then(() => {}).catch(e => alert('Error starting GoogleAnalytics == '+ e));
```

I have used this code inside my component ts file, and added  a alert for `.then()` method.

when i checked in device its giving null for the result and i cant see any active users in analytics dashboard.

Comment: are you getting any error in catch callback ??

Comment: no error ,then is executing and resutling null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Don't know what wrong here, but always i'm checking for the alert response.
as i said its always returning 'null' so i thought its not working properly....but ios returning as null for successful connection and i'm able to see the activity in google analytics dashboard